# SLURM leaves nextflow jobs job pending in node

Tags: mpi, slurm, hpc, nextflow

I am running a nextflow script on my HPC which is run by SLURM. My job consists of processing thousands of small files. So heavy I/O but very little computational effort per job ~ 5min per job. When I submit my job Next-Flow will spawn jobs and they will be processed but they sit largely idle for most of the time. I spoke to the admin and they said once I am assigned resources I have them for the full time I requested. I am confused why I should be in pending status at all.

Any help is much appreciated

**my submission script**

```
#!/bin/bash


#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --partition=general
#SBATCH --mem=500MB
#SBATCH -t 02-00:00:00
#SBATCH --mail-type=BEGIN,REQUEUE,FAIL,END 
#SBATCH --mail-user= me@email.com

work_dir=/pine/scr/
image_set=$1
export NXF_CLUSTER_SEED=$(shuf -i 0-16777216 -n 1)

srun $work_dir/nextflow -c $work_dir/nextflow.config run $work_dir/image_processing.nf --folder $image_set -with-mpi
sacct -j $SLURM_JOB_ID --format='JobID,user,elapsed, cputime, totalCPU,MaxRSS,MaxVMSize, ncpus,NTasks,ExitCode'
```

**my nextflow.config file**

```
process.container = '/pine/scr/m/j/mjrich/longleaf.sif'
singularity.enabled = true
singularity.autoMounts = true


process {
  executor='slurm'
  memory='500MB'
  pollInterval = '10 min'
  dumpInterval = '10 min'
  exitReadTimeout = '10 min'
  killBatchSize = 50
}
```

my directives on the offending process

```
    publishDir "$projectDir/processed_images/$folder", mode: 'move', overwrite: true, pattern: 'image-*.jpeg'
    publishDir "$projectDir/processed_images/$folder/failed", mode: 'move', overwrite: true, pattern: 'failed-*.jpeg'
    errorStrategy 'ignore'
    maxForks 5
    memory '500 MB'
    time '10m'
    cpus 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your `pollInterval` of 10 minutes might be too high for the anticipated job duration. From the Nextflow [Scope *executor*](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html#scope-executor), docs:

> pollInterval - Determines how often a poll occurs to check for a
> process termination.

Perhaps try changing this to:

```
pollInterval = '30 sec'
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment this helped a bit though not at the root of my problem. Slurm will put more jobs up but they wont run. I reserved 1 node and all the cores on the node but it still waits. I have horrible efficiency because the system is waiting for something.

Comment: @TheCodeNovice I'm not familiar with Slurm but I wonder if setting `maxForks 5` is problematic? Have you tried removing the [maxForks](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#maxforks) directive? I don't think this will be the root of the problem though since Nextflow is launching jobs and they are queuing.

Comment: Maxforks 5 will limit the number of jobs nextflow submits to SLURM to 5 concurrent jobs. Increasing the polling interval will help with efficiency, but can not be the root cause of jobs staying pending in SLURM. Do your jobs stay pending in SLURM if you submit 5 or 10 of  them via a manually written sbatch instead of via nextflow @TheCodeNovice?

Comment: @Pallie No if I were to submit the scripts individually it is no problem. My understanding is when I request resources I have exclusive rights to the cores for that duration so it should function like it is running locally on my screen with no delay between processing one file and the next. That is not the behavior I see. I do know that nextflow submits under my name and that requesting more than 1 core on my submission scrip does not help.

Comment: @TheCodeNovice I found this example, not sure if setting `--ntasks` and `--cpus-per-task` makes any sense: https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/ignite.html?highlight=nxf_cluster_seed#linux-slurm-launcher